# jQuery take array from php file and display in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is my php script to display json data:

```
$get_chat = "SELECT * FROM chat WHERE u_id1='$u_id' && u_id2=2 ORDER BY data DESC";
$run_chat = $conn->query($get_chat);
if ($run_chat->num_rows > 0) {
while($chat_row = $run_chat->fetch_assoc()) {
echo json_encode( $chat_row );
}
}
```

This is my result from php file:

```
{"u_id1":"1","content":"ae","u_id2":"2","data":"17\/03\/27 02:02"}
{"u_id1":"1","content":"ax","u_id2":"2","data":"17\/03\/27 02:01"}
{"u_id1":"1","content":"fd","u_id2":"2","data":"17\/03\/26 11:49"}
{"u_id1":"1","content":"hh","u_id2":"2","data":"17\/03\/26 11:47"}
```

And now I whant to display all of this in html.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your work. We're not going to write your code for you.

Comment: I want to make simple live chat app for my website. so I need to find any way to do this. I do not know how to take this array from my script and display than. that's is. If you know some info please say me. thanks for advance!

Comment: @OTFluge please update your question with all pertinent information, clearing stating what you are trying to achieve, showing an example where applicable, and include any code that you yourself have written thus far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
<?php while($chat_row = $run_chat->fetch_assoc()): ?>

     <p><?= $chat_row['content']; ?></p>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

No need to use json_encode unless you want a Javascript object from my understanding, and it doesn't seem like that's what you're trying to do.